# Writing Responses To File Java

Tags: java, do-while

I have written a magic 8-ball program with 20 different possible responses. Each time a response is randomly selected, I am trying to write that response to a file. However, within the do-while loop in the main method, the line "writeFile(answer);" is not working because "answer" is out scope. I am having trouble trying to fix it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String terminate = "Q";
    String Question = "";
    System.out.println("I am the all-knowing Magic 8 Ball!");
    String something = "This is an easter egg!";

    do {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Ask your question here or enter 'Q' to quit:");
        Question = scnr.nextLine();
        continueGame(Question);
        writeFile(answer);
    } while (!(terminate.equals(Question)));
   }

public static void continueGame(String Question) {

    char terminate = 'Q';
    char condition = Question.charAt(0);

    if (condition == terminate) 
    {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    try 
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int choice;
        choice = 1 + rand.nextInt(20);
        responseOptions(choice, Question);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid");
    }
}

public static String responseOptions(int choice, String answer)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1: answer = "Response: It is certain"; break;
        case 2: answer = "Response: It is decidely so"; break;
        case 3: answer = "Response: Without a doubt"; break;
        case 4: answer = "Response: Yes, definitely"; break;
        case 5: answer = "Response: You may rely on it"; break;
        case 6: answer = "Response: As I see it, yes"; break;
        case 7: answer = "Response: Most likely"; break;
        case 8: answer = "Response: Outlook good"; break;
        case 9: answer = "Response: Yes"; break;
        case 10: answer = "Response: Signs point to yes"; break;
        case 11: answer = "Response: Reply hazy, try again"; break;
        case 12: answer = "Response: Ask again later"; break;
        case 13: answer = "Response: Better not tell you now"; break;
        case 14: answer = "Response: Cannot predict now"; break;
        case 15: answer = "Response: Concentrate and ask again"; break;
        case 16: answer = "Response: Don't count on it"; break;
        case 17: answer = "Response: My reply is no"; break;
        case 18: answer = "Response: My sources say no"; break;
        case 19: answer = "Response: Outlook not so good"; break;
        case 20: answer = "Response: Very doubtful"; break;
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(answer);

    return answer;
}

public static String writeFile(String something) {

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("filename.txt", true);
        fw.write(something);
        fw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return something;
}
}
```

Comment: What are you even trying to refer to? The only thing in there called `answer` is a method parameter.

Comment: It is a bad idea to re-assign a method parameter.

Comment: @AndyTurner the different answer choices in the responseOptions method are under the variable "answer"

Comment: you should also terminate based on the entire question being equal to Q and not just the first character in the parameter passed to continueGame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd slightly change the `responseOptions` method. It only needs the choice parameter:

```
public static String responseOptions(int choice) {
    String answer;
    switch (choice) {
      // ...
```

Then, we should change `continueGame` a bit:

```
public static String continueGame(String Question) {
    // ...
        return responseOptions(choice);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return"Error: Invalid"
    }
}
```

and finally, in main

```
// ...
String answer = continueGame(Question);
// ...
```

So basically we return the answer from the responsesOptions method back to main to be able to pass it to the print method.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could change `public static void continueGame(String Question)` to `public static String continueGame(String Question)` and place a return statement like:  `return  responseOptions(choice, Question);`

Finally in main you can write:

```
writeFile( continueGame(Question) );
```

instead of:

```
continueGame(Question);
        writeFile(answer);
```

Comment: just add he needs to change responseOptions(choice, Question); to return responseOptions(choice, Question);

Comment: But if I understand correctly,   responseOptions(choice, Question); already has a return statement ...

Comment: @coder for some reason it says that it can't find the variable "choice"

Comment: i mean inside the continueGame function change that line so it returns the String answer returned by responseOptions

Answer (score 0):

Take note that `responseOptions` is returning a value, yet you ignore it.

```
int choice;
choice = 1 + rand.nextInt(20);
responseOptions(choice, Question); // Question is not assigned to the return value
```

Overall, I think you should try this instead.

```
public static String responseOptions(int choice)
{
    String [] answers = new String[] {
        "It is certain",
        "It is decidely so",
        "Without a doubt"
    };
    return "Response: " + answers[choice - 1];
}
```

(Ideally `answers` could be defined elsewhere as a class-variable.)

And call like so

```
// within continueGame()
int choice = 1 + rand.nextInt(20);   
String answer = responseOptions(choice); 
writeFile(answer); // Write it here, where it is in scope
```